# Which is the fastest way to replicate oracle database deployed in RDS?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, database-backups, rds, rman

For example: Lets say i have two database `DB1 and DB2`. Now my requirement is to refresh data from `DB1` to `DB2` **every night**. `DB1` is live database and `DB2` is for non business users for data analysis.

**My questions:**

```
1) What must be the tool i should use for my requirement? I need a solution that is fast, since the database copy has to be done everyday.
2) Does AWS have any tool to automate the backup and restore the data?
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a load of ways to do this and the answer comes down to what storage you're using, are they on the same server and then ultimately the size of the database.

RMAN's more a backup / recovery tool but definitely a runner for cloning. If you're not sure what RMAN does then I wouldn't even start to implement it as it's very tricky if you aren't super comfortable with Oracle DB's.

My recommendation is just use Oracle datapump, export the schema's you need to a dump file then ship it over and import them into the other database making sure to overwrite/drop the existing schemas.

Other than doing a differential clone at a SAN level this is probably the quickest and definitely easiest way to get it done